# Is there fast way to present Pearson correlation on the upper panel and Spearman correlation on the lower panel?

Tags: r, graphics, correlation

The library `corrgram` gives an opportunity to draw elegant correlograms. However, there is no easy way in the documentation to obtain both Spearman and Pearson correlations on the same graph.

Perhaps computing a correlation matrices for both coefficients and paste them would be an option, but it does not seem to be the proper way.

I think the image will explain properly what I want to get :

[image]

I want to get:

```
cors <- cor(state.x77, method = "pearson")
corsSp <- cor(state.x77, method = "spearman")
for(i in 1:nrow(cors))
{
for(j in i:ncol(cors))
{
cors[i,j] <- corsSp[i,j]
m[i,j] <- j
}
}
corrgram(cors, type = "corr")
```

in a more elegant way.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data set or a use an inbuilt data set to illustrate failed attempts?

Comment: `corrgram` only allows for pearson-correlations, source: https://github.com/kwstat/corrgram/blob/master/R/corrgram.r

Comment: I've edited my question, providing some code.

In order to get Spearman correlations, I use
    corrgram(state.x77, cor.method = "spearman")

Answer (score 2):

You can try to rebuild your graph by hand via `ggplot` which gives pretty similiar results (except the patterned background):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

## transform the cor matrix (with pearons and spearmann coeeficients) 
cor_cleaned <- cors %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column("x") %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  gather(y, cor, -x) %>%
  mutate(x   = factor(x, unique(x)),
         y   = factor(y, rev(levels(x))),
         dir = factor(sign(cor)))

cor_tri <- cor_cleaned %>%
  filter(x != y)

cor_diag <- cor_cleaned %>%
  filter(x == y)

ggplot(cor_tri, aes(x, y, alpha = abs(cor), fill = dir)) +
  geom_tile(show.legend = FALSE, color = "gray") +
  geom_tile(show.legend = FALSE, color = "gray", fill = NA, data = cor_diag) +
  geom_text(aes(label = y), data = cor_diag, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("1" = "navy", "-1" = "red")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text  = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image: Corrgram with ggplot]

Answer (score 2):

Taking for example these data:

```
df = data.frame(x = runif(100),
                y = runif(100),
                z = runif(100),
                w = runif(100),
                v = runif(100),
                u = runif(100))
```

Computing the correlation matrix:

```
library("dplyr")
mat = matrix(NA, nrow = ncol(df), ncol = ncol(df)) %>%
  `row.names<-`(names(df)) %>%
  `colnames<-`(names(df))


mat[upper.tri(mat)] = cor(df,method="pearson")[upper.tri(mat)]
mat[lower.tri(mat)] = cor(df,method="spearman")[lower.tri(mat)]
```

Converting from long to wide format:

```
cor.long = reshape2::melt(mat)
```

Then plot:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("RColorBrewer")

pal = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")))

ggplot(cor.long, aes(Var1, factor(Var2, rev(levels(Var2))), fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Var1), data = cor.long %>% filter(Var1 == Var2)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = value %>% round(digits = 3)), data = cor.long %>% filter(Var1 != Var2)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df$Var2))) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = pal(100), na.value  = "white", limits=c(-.5,.5)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(angle = 45),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A different way to calculate your correlation matrix:

```
mycor <- Vectorize(function(i, j) {
   method <- ifelse(i>j, "pearson", "spearman")
   cor(state.x77[,i], state.x77[,j], method = method)
})
sqn <- 1:ncol(state.x77)
cors <- outer(sqn, sqn, FUN=mycor)
```